# Cloudflare denies my access when I scraped a website

Tags: web-scraping, cloudflare, vps

I used [cloudscraper](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper) to scrape this website [oddschecker](https://www.oddschecker.com/football/english/premier-league). I ran it locally on my computer, it works fine. But when I used a Digital Ocean VPS, Cloudflare denied my access, with an error message saying:

> #### Access denied
>
> This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.

I'm not sure what that means - is Cloudflare blocking my VPS's IP address? Do I have to use a proxy to scrape it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this error you are seeing is due to a Cloudflare [firewall rule that you are hitting](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029779472-Troubleshooting-Cloudflare-1XXX-errors#error1020). The Cloudflare firewall has a list of 20 different triggers to block/allow requests so it's hard to say exactly if is the IP trigger that's being blocked in this case but that's generally the case. See some examples [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/recipes).

If you are not even able to access the site from the beginning using a new IP address/VPS, it's possible the trigger has to do with the behaviour of your request rather than the source - e.g. rate limiting (although the error message would be different in this case), number of requests per minute, method used to access, reputation of network block (ASN) etc.

Comment: yeah it's pretty werid. i ran it locally and it worked perfectly fine even though i ran it repeatedly.